# Proof addition is commutative in $ \mathbb R$

Tags: solution-verification, arithmetic

I want to formally prove that $ + $ is commutative in $ \mathbb{R} $.

I thought about the following proof so far:

Given $ n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{N} $.

$ A = \{x \in \mathbb{N} \mid 1 \le x \le n_1\}$

$ B = \{n_1 + 1, n_1 + 2, ..., n_1 + n_2\} $

Of course $ A \cap B = \emptyset, \left|A\right| = n_1, \left|B\right| = n_2$.

Therefore $ \left|A \cup B\right| = n_1 + n_2 = \left|B \cup A\right| = n_2 + n_1, \Rightarrow n_1 + n_2 = n_2 + n_1.$

But even if this proof is valid, it only works for $ \mathbb{N} $.

So I thought of another proof, take two disjoint square in the plane, therefore the area of the two squares combined is $ n_1 + n_2 $, and at the same time, it's also $ n_2 + n_1 $.

Is there any alternative proof for the commutativity of $ + $ in $ \mathbb{R} $?

Comment: why would you take squares instead of segments on a line? Anyway, I suggest you first define what $\Bbb R$ means.

Comment: You are going to have to give a formal definition of $\mathbb{R}$, if you want to formally prove anything about it.

Comment: @Surb Do you mean the definition with the Cauchy Sequences?

Answer (score 2):

As both @Surb and @Violet Flame have mentioned in the comments, in order to formally prove properties of ${\mathbb{R}}$ you need first to give an actual formal construction of ${\mathbb{R}}$. Two notable constructions are the Dedekind construction or the Cauchy construction, both of which build ${\mathbb{R}}$ out of ${\mathbb{Q}}$. In both cases, commutativity of addition in ${\mathbb{R}}$ is easy to see from the commutativity of addition in ${\mathbb{Q}}$. This can be easily seen from commutativity of addition and multiplication in ${\mathbb{Z}}$, which can be easily seen from commutativity of addition and multiplication in ${\mathbb{N}}$. To build ${\mathbb{N}}$, you can use, for instance, the Peano axioms, from which commutativity of addition and multiplication comes from a bunch of induction

Answer (score 1):

You can define real numbers as Cauchy sequences of rational numbers. Then the proposed property results from the commutativity from the rational numbers. You can check out the construction of the naturals, integers, rationals and reals in the book of Terence Tao called Analysis I, for example.

Comment: But wouldn't I have to prove that $ + $ in $ \mathbb{Q} $ is commutative?

Comment: @talopl Indeed. That is why I mentioned the proposed reference.